# cmd prompt turned from window mode to full screen mode

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I was working on cmd and certainly I made changes in properties from window mode to full screen.
Now every when I open a new window or existing one using win+r [cmd] I am only getting a full screen cmd prompt.
Please provide me the solution to restore it in previous mode [window mode] cmd.

Comment: right click, properties Run: Normal Window

Comment: Why not just go change the properties you changed back to what they were?  Aside from that, I'm a little confused, since the Windows 7 command prompt doesn't actually do "full screen" text modes. Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing, and/or tell us which properties you changed?

Answer (score 2):

Change the Height and Width of the CMD window size. Open the CMD > Properties > Layout and change the size here.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

otherwise

- Go to C:->Windows->system32->cmd
- right click cmd select send to->create desktop shortcut
- Go to the properties of shortcut cmd set run field as Normal windows in shortcut tab.

Answer (score 0):

In CMD run notepad to get you out of fullscreen and then right click the top left of the minimized CMD window to reach the option window as shown in the screenshot from a previous answer (vernbutech's).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this  problem in windows XP  where the dos window covers the whole screen for all future execution of cmd.  Nowhere to find the tab to click properties.  None of the above works.  Properties on the shortcut only works for that cmd in windows mode.  If you ever run (cmd) in the run command is different from running from a shorcut in windows.  I changed the properties in the shortcut but still ran full screen from the run command.
The solution is to click tab key  to go to another program running so that the full
screen dos will be minimized at the taskbar.  right click properties on the minimized dos from the taskbar and set default and you're go back to the default window size.

Answer (score 0):

press ALT+ Enter

Got it from the following link:
https://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Full-Screen-Command-Prompt